# Azure Blob Storage sync: Get list of touched files

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-cdn

I would like to automatically invalidate the (cdn) cache for objects changed by invoking the command `az storage blob sync`. Therefore I would need the list of files touched by sync.

The best option I have found is to give it the verbose flag, parse the generated log file and apply a filter to get the files touched. This feels a bit hackish so I was wondering if there is a better option.

Comment: How about filtering files by last modified time?

Comment: @StanleyGong: I think this would not work in some situations, for example CI, when the file is regenerated in a clean build job, but still the same as on the server.

Comment: @StanleyGong: After figuring out az sync (and other pendants) also relies on modified times, I revoke my previous comment and think thats the best way. (And I would accept it as answer)

Comment: Thanks for your response and I am glad to know my suggestion is helpful. I have summarized it as an answer, could you please kindly accept it to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter files by last modified time, and based on your research, `az sync` also relies on modified times and meets your requirements here.